# Jasper Report style isBold="true" not working in a conditionalStyle

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using the Jasper Report library for Java v6.19.1 and the Report Design plugin for Eclipse.

I created this conditional style and I applied it to a text field.

```
<style name="myStyleBold">
<conditionalStyle>
<conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{misura} == null]]></conditionExpression>
<style isBold="true" isItalic="true" isUnderline="true" isStrikeThrough="true"/>
</conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

All formats are working (isItalic="true" isUnderline="true" isStrikeThrough="true"), but the isBold="true" is never applied.

Anyone has the same issue or solved it?

Comment: You can try to simplify template and conditional style to debug this issue. Conditional styles like this are working fine

Comment: @AlexK I added (isItalic="true" isUnderline="true" isStrikeThrough="true") only for test, to see if the condition expression is working, and in fact it is working because these styles are applied. Only "isBold=true" not. I will try to do this in the master report (this conditional style is applied in a subreport now, maybe could be this the problem).

Comment: It can be also a font issue also. How did you check the output result? Did you check the pdf file? Do you have another text fields with bold text that look good?

Comment: @AlexK I check the result in the PDF. Yes I have another text field with the same font and bold and it works (without conditional style).

Comment: @AlexK in the master report it works! So, could be an issue of subreports...

Comment: @AlexK solved as showed in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Solved. The value must be < EREDITATO >. It was "false".

[image]